# I need a better explanation of the 100 doors program

Tags: c

How would I do this in 1 loop since I need to loop again and close every second door? Do they want me to loop through the program 100 times? Should I be using pointers ?

Comment: Something something parity of the number of prime factors something something...

Comment: Welcome to the site! This really isn't how it works. You need to make an effort first, not just dump your homework here. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should loop through the program 100 times if you want to simulate this behavior.

But if you want to know the final condition(Open/Close) then you can have better algorithm:

> As every perfect square number only have odd number of factor, if number is perfect square then final condition of door is open otherwise door is close.

If you are interested  see [perfect square number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number) and [Why  perfect squares only have odd numbers of factor](https://web.archive.org/web/20180130225121/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/72126.html) .

Comment: Something to ponder: Does 0 have an odd number of factors, an infinite number or an infinite number that is odd? Hmmm? ;-)

Comment: @chux Huh, that's why door 0(If any) always half close - half open :3

Comment: Yes, zero is a pesky number.